# In the Grenadines, how could you get scuba tanks for diving if already on a boat?

Tags: diving

We will be traveling from St Lucia -> Grenada via the Grenadines on a private sailboat.  Travel over land to pickup/return dive gear would most likely be a nightmare.

In the Grenadines are there good places to pick up dive gear and tanks without having to go far inland.

Comment: What did you find when googling for "scuba Grenadines"?

Comment: Several places that want me to come to their shop, get on their boat and go dive with them.  I'm guessing the islands are so small and remote they don't get much in the way of boat traffic.

Comment: Any dive shop is highly likely to both rent gear and refil tanks for anyone who shows up, even if they don't want to do a dive trip. If its in doubt a phone call to them should tell you definitively.

Answer (score 4):

Couple of parts to this answer:

- In the Grenadines, there is not anywhere that is far inland, and even on St. Vincent you cannot get more than about 6 miles from the sea.
- Dive shops are almost always at the dock/marina/shore - this may sound obvious, but they are where they will get business: right next to the sea.

Specifically:

Dive shops are on the west coast of Bequiea, in Port Elizabeth; On the south west coast of St Vincent, at the Blue Lagoon, the west coast of Carriacou etc

They all have a good web presence, so as @uncovery mentioned, you can google for "Grenadines dive" or "Grenadines scuba"